# Matlab 2-D density plot

Tags: matlab, binning, density-plot

I am trying to do a density plot for a data containing two columns with different ranges. The RMSD column is [0-2] and Angle is [0-200] ranges.

My data in the file is like this:

```
0.0225370 37.088  
0.1049553 35.309  
0.0710002 33.993  
0.0866880 34.708  
0.0912664 33.011  
0.0932054 33.191  
0.1083590 37.276  
0.1104145 34.882  
0.1027977 34.341  
0.0896688 35.991  
0.1047578 36.457  
0.1215936 38.914  
0.1105484 35.051  
0.0974138 35.533  
0.1390955 33.601  
0.1333878 32.133  
0.0933365 35.714  
0.1200465 33.038  
0.1155794 33.694  
0.1125247 34.522  
0.1181806 37.890  
0.1291700 38.871
```

1. I want both x and y axis to be binned 1/10th of the range
2. The 0 of both the axis to be starting in the same
3. Print the number of elements in each grid of the matrix like this and make a density plot based on these number of elements

   ```
      0 0.1 0.2 (RMSD)   
   0  0 1 3
   20 2 0 4
   40 1 0 5
   60 0 0 2
   (Angle)
   ```

I can find ways to do 1-D binning but then I am stumped about how to make a density plot from those values and havent even dared to attempt2-D binning + plotting.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [`hist3`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html). Assuming you want to specifty bin *edges* (not bin centers), use

```
result = hist3(data, 'Edges', {[0 .1 .2], [0 20 40 60]}).';
```

where `data` denotes your data.

From the linked documentation:

> `hist3(X,'Edges',edges)`, where `edges` is a two-element cell array of numeric vectors with monotonically non-decreasing values, uses a 2-D grid of bins with edges at `edges{1}` in the first dimension and at `edges{2}` in the second. The (`i`,`j`)th bin includes the value `X(k,:)` if
>
> `edges{1}(i) <= X(k,1) < edges{1}(i+1)` 
> `edges{2}(j) <= X(k,2) < edges{2}(j+1)`

With your example data this gives

```
result =
     0     0     0
     8    14     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```

Comment: I am doing the following

load rmsd_angle_all_combined.list ; 
>> result = hist3(rmsd_angle_all_combined, 'Edges', {[0 .1 .2 .4 .6 .8 1 1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 2], [0 20 40 60 80 100 120 140 160 180 200]}).';
>>imagesc

This is resulting in a picture which has 0-70 on both axis. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @user1504209 I don't know... the output size of `hist3` is determined by the number of edges

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't have [Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html) to run bivariate histogram ([hist3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html)), it may be more practical using an alternative to solve 2-D hist problem. The following function generates the same output

```
function N = hist3_alt(x,y,edgesX,edgesY)
N = zeros(length(edgesY)-1,length(edgesX)-1);
[~,~,binX] = histcounts(x,edgesX);
for ii=1:numel(edgesX)-1
    N(:,ii) = (histcounts(y(binX==ii),edgesY))';
end
```

It's simple and efficient. Then you could run the function like this:

```
N = hist3_alt(x,y,[0:0.1:2],[0:20:200])
```