# A density plot using 2 coordinates columns and a weight column

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, density-plot

I have a matrix with 3 columns. The first two columns are coordinates and the third is weight or intensity.

```
newmat = [ 27.37  -45.69   14.47
           27.37  -45.68   18.58
           27.37  -45.67   29.05
           27.37  -45.66   51.7
            ...     ...     ... ]
```

I have already created a scatter plot:

[image: scatterplot]

However, I'd like to have something like a density plot (as the second plot [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/224560-binning-2d-set-of-coordinates?s_tid=answers_rc1-2_p2_MLT)). I have tried to use `hist3` function as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747718/matlab-2-d-density-plot), but I didn't figure out how to take into account the third column - weight.

Comment: From the link to the picture: `out = accumarray([idxx,idxy], 1);` You replace that by `out = accumarray([idxx,idxy], weights);`

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly does it help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a matrix from the data in `newmat` (using the functions [`sortrows`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html), [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), and [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)) and plot it as an [image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html):

```
newmat = sortrows(newmat, [1 2]);  % Sort the first two columns in ascending order
[x, ~, newmat(:, 1)] = unique(newmat(:, 1));     % Make numeric indices for column 1
[y, ~, newmat(:, 2)] = unique(newmat(:, 2));     % Make numeric indices for column 2
M = accumarray(newmat(:, 1:2), newmat(:, 3)).';  % Build the matrix
imagesc(x, y, M);
```

Here's some sample data similar to your format:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(0:0.1:2, 3:0.1:5);
Z = peaks(21);
newmat = [X(:) Y(:) Z(:)];
```

And here's the plot the above code produces from that data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very useful!